# How to find and show duplicate lines in a richtextbox?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a feature that checks a RichTextBox in Visual Basic for text and shows in a listview the content of the line that exists multiple times and how many times it appears.

I'm not really sure how to start here as I'm not working with RichTextBoxes in Visual Basic often so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the Lines property of the textbox and take it from there.

Comment: `dim lines = [RichTextBox].Lines dim dupes = lines.GroupBy(Function(l) l.GetHashCode()).Select(Function(g) new with {.Value = g.First(), .Count = g.Count()}).ToList()`

Comment: @Jimi I will try your solution tomorrow. Does it do exactly what I need, take the duplicates in a richtextbox and put them into a listview, or do I need to change anything?

Comment: That code returns a collection of objects where the `Value` property is a string representing one of the lines of text and the `Count` property is the number of times that string repeats in the whole content. You can add a `Where()` filter to only include strings that have a `Count > 0`. And/or `OrderBy()` the list based on the `Count` value etc.

Comment: I'd consider myself kind of a noob... I have no idea how functions work so I dont know where I should add the Where() clause. Can you show me an example how I should add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this hasn't got an answer yet and I found a solution I will provide you with mine.

First of all I find all the duplicates with the following code. It searches all duplicates in a richtextbox and puts them into a list.

```
  Dim duplicates As List(Of String) =
  RichTextBoxWithDuplicates.Lines.GroupBy(Function(n) n) _
  .Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1) _
  .Select(Function(g) g.First) _
  .ToList()
```

To further use this list I found it easier to convert it to an array.

```
Dim ArrayResult As String() = duplicates.ToArray
```

Finally, I load the array into a RichTextBox to show it to the user.

```
RichTextBoxDups.Lines = ArrayResult
```